# Replace AND operator with OR to get the same output

Tags: sql, boolean-algebra

I have this code:

```
IF (x>5 AND y=4) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line("Y");
ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line("N");
```

My question is: how do you change the code if you can not use AND as the operator but instead, you have to use OR to have the same logic and get the same result?

Comment: `OR` will not return the same result, so I don't understand the question.

Comment: I received this task from my senior colleague: how do you transform this condition : x>5 AND y=4 if you can not use AND operator, but only OR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DeMorgan's Law to rewrite it:

```
NOT (p AND q) == (NOT p) OR (NOT q)
```

So, in your case

```
IF (x>5 AND y=4) THEN "Y" ELSE "N"
IF (x<=5 OR y<>4) THEN "N" ELSE "Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

Or and AND operator have completely different logic, you cannot use AND as the operator but instead, you have to use OR to have the same logic and get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the line to read like this, it will work with only the OR operator:

IF (x<=5 OR y!=4) THEN dbms_output.put_line("N"); ELSE dbms_output.put_line("Y");=

The outcome is the same, but the logic is slightly different.